# Using C# library in Unreal Engine C++

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper, unreal-engine4

Hi I wish to use a C# library in a C++ application which is in unreal engine.
Is there any easy way to wrap a C# library using C++ ??

I have looked up how to wrap a C# library but there only seems to be posts on how to use a C++ library in C#.

Really appreciate the help thanks.

Comment: You'd need to embed a runtime, most likely Mono: That's not trivial and a lot of work

Comment: Doesn't answer your question exactly, but this is partly why C++/CLI exists.  You could rewrite/wrap using it instead.

Answer (score 2):

C# allows you to perform interoperability calls to c++ and c libraries. Although not exposed, you could manipulate your assembly to force the reverse (this is done via ildasm, however, this is a trick and I won't go in details).

To achieve what you ask, you have to manually fill in the gap from your c++ host and your c# library. One way, not clearly at zero effort, is to create a new assembly in MC++ (ie c++ with a hosted clr) . This bridging assembly would expose the api in order to be used by your c++ language, while it can access your c# library to reuse the logic.

This is not a trivial task as you need to manually marshal the data structures as you are going "against the designed use case".

Embedding a runtime, in my opinion, would have the same effort. In any case, you should be careful though, because your unreal engine is resource intensive and performances could get a sensible hit. Furthermore, the c# part has a different memory management system that can not be optimal when stressed by the unreal engine.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think I might just run the C# library on an external library and use sockets to pass the Data into Unreal Engine way too inexperienced to try anything else.

Comment: You are welcome! That's a way too, there is no "right" way to do that, as it depends on all the requirements and constraints you have.